# Updating session variables

Tags: php, mysql

So in a separate php file I write the amount of points the user has and other information like email from a database into a PHP session:

```
// write user data into PHP SESSION
$_SESSION['user_name']         = $result_row->user_name;
$_SESSION['user_email']        = $result_row->user_email;
$_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
$_SESSION['user_Points']       = $result_row->user_Points;
```

Next, I have a separate php file when the user logs in to show the amount of points he has:

```
// The amount of points the user has
Hey, you currently have 
<?php echo $_SESSION['user_Points'];?>
```

It works fine, but when I update the amount of points in phpmyadmin the user has, the only way to refresh the points count is to log-out and log-in back again. I know that the session sets the variables only one time, but I want to ask if there's a way to update the points without logging out and logging in again like: refreshing the page, using JavaScript or other ways. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to retrieve the value from DB every time user reload the page instead of save it on `$_SESSION` when he/she logins.

If want to keep `$_SESSION['user_Points']` you could do a function where at the beginning of the file where you show user points, you update `$_SESSION['user_Points']`, retrieve it from DB using, for example, `$_SESSION['user_email']` in WHERE clause, something like in the query:

```
$your_query = 'SELECT user_points FROM users WHERE user_email = '.$_SESSION['user_email'].'';
```

After that, if user reload page, `$_SESSION['user_Points']` will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to read the db every time when dealing with points rather than cache them in the session. You could just keep the userid in the session so you can do a db lookup for the points in realtime.  But if you really wanted to delay reading the new values for a certain amount of time, you could so something like this.

First save a updated time into the session on login also:

```
$_SESSION['LAST_UPDATED'] = time();
```

Then in subsequent requests, check if a certain amount of time has elapsed since the updated time that's in the session, and if so, update the session variables in question:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_UPDATED']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_UPDATED'] > 120))
{
    //its been 2 minutes since last update
    //pull values from db again, and store in session again
    .....
    $_SESSION['user_Points']       = $result_row->user_Points;

    //set the updated time
    $_SESSION['LAST_UPDATED'] = time();
}
```

Comment: How would I go about doing the realtime updating from a database?

Comment: @EdvinasMazintas I meant "realtime" in the since that every time the page is refreshed or they go to a new page, you read the database using PDO or mysqli_.

Comment: I see, the thing is, the page that shows after you login is different from the one you submit data with on login. So I can't use variables from the other file, I get errors: Notice: Undefined variable: result_row in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/views/logged_in.php on line 7

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /storage/emulated/legacy/htdocs/views/logged_in.php on line 7

Comment: @EdvinasMazintas That's what `include` is for. You make a db.php with all the variables needed to connect to the db and include it in every page that needs to read the db

Comment: I know that, connected to the db successfully, still get those 2 errors. Shall I post the whole 2 php files?